# Rails link_to without ? symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a user profile page what I'm looking for is to have

```
/profile/Nick
```

on the view I'm using

```
profile_path(:nick => current_user.nick)
```

While that works it does give me a link like

```
/profile?nick=Nick
```

the routes include

```
get 'profile/:nick' => 'users#show'
```

The routes work already if I write the address by hand, is just generating it not the way I would want it

is there a way to pass a parameter in a way that it will create a / instead of the old ?=

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `profile_path(current_user.nick)` instead of what you have at the moment.

Comment: Right sorry forgot to say it earlier that the routes already include get 'profile/:nick' => 'users#show', it doesnt work however, if I write it by hand it will work no problem, is just that when it generates the url from the view is not the "prettier" kind